# cant see c/c+ on visual studio 2019

Tags: c++

hi im currently fallowing a udemy course and it my first road bump after 2 hours still cant figure this out please can someone help i should be able to see a tab that says c/c++ but i cant. i have made sure my c++ package is installed. im using vsc 2019 and i just cant get it working any help would be very appreciated

i have tried to "modify" vs in visual studio installer and i didnt work.

i have ask the udemy instructor and no answer

any help would be so useful thanks

[image]

(if image didnt load here is the link to imgur) https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbddN.jpg

Comment: Follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#:~:text=Workloads%20contain%20the%20features%20you%20need%20for%20the,to%20do%2C%20when%20you%20want%20to%20do%20it.).  Make sure Desktop development with C++ is checked.

Comment: What you have a picture of is the Visual Studio project settings for your C++ project, "cyborg battle". So that implies that you have Visual Studio installed and have a project loaded.  What exactly is your issue? Can you compile and run the code?

Comment: Assuming the Udemy course is asking you to modify the properties of something, are you sure you've clicked the right item? E.g. the _solution_ as compared to the _project_?

Comment: Before Linker there should be a C/C++ item. I am unsure why you don't have that for a Win32 project. Did you try selecting just a single configuration like Debug?

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that you have installed the Desktop development with C++ workload. That should be enough to get you started. However, the C/C++ options appear in the project properties only after you have added a C or C++ source file.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it additionally asks to download/install C/C++ packages via different dialog boxes popping up. If it has asked, please make sure you installed it properly without a power failure in between. Or else as a last resort, try repeating the installation process.